# Absolute hyperlink is performing relative

Tags: html, server, cpanel, absolute, relative-url

There’s an image on my website of the Patreon logo that I want to open up to my Patreon if clicked on. The link is coded as an absolute link but opens up relative.

For example:

Starting site: https://buttertoast.com

Intended site: https://patreon.com/buttertoast

Unwanted result: https://buttertoast.com/patreon.com/buttertoast

```html
<a href="https://patreon.com/buttertoast">
  <img src="images/Digital-Patreon-Wordmark_White.png" alt="alt" class="u-image u-image-default u-image-1" data-image-width="2430" data-image-height="495">
</a>
```

As seen above the href link to my understanding is correct, don't understand why it would opening as relative instead of jumping to the intended absolute location.

Comment: So I mean it's not actually going to Patreon as intended, it's almost as if it's looking for the site within my website files. I'm a bit of a noob sorry. so instead of clicking on the image and it jumping to the Patreon page "https://patreon.com/buttertoast" it's trying to stay on the site in return https://buttertoast.com/patreon.com/buttertoast

Comment: Your code, as is, is working, we can't guess without additional info :)

Comment: Is that about the redirection that you have with https://buttertoast.com/patreon.com/buttertoast ?
I don't understand

Comment: yes, it's about the redirction.

Comment: can i see you htaccess  file?

Comment: you need to put buttertoast folder on the www repertories of patreon's site server
or revise the .htaccess file

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start to do that. To make it simple to see what I'm talking about, the actual website is skywayrecordsllc.com, if you go to the bottom and click the Patreon button it will jump you to a 404 error page and not the Patreon page I want. I don't understand why when the href has the site in it.

Comment: you shourd change 
data-href="patreon.com/skywayrecordsllc"
with
data-href="http://patreon.com/skywayrecordsllc"

Comment: with http:// before patreon

Comment: I'm doing that, that's why I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
You should write `data-href="http://patreon.com/skywayrecordsllc"` instead `data-href="patreon.com/skywayrecordsllc"`

Comment: I changed it and still nothing. Instead of going to "https://www.patreon.com/skywayrecordsllc", it's jumping  "https://skywayrecordsllc.com/patreon.com/skywayrecordsllc" which gives an 404 error page

Comment: I think there’s an another issues because when I update it in Chanel’s file manager, it’s not acknowledging the change on the webpage